# Search index keeps resetting itself to certain percentage done

Tags: 6, search

On a productive site (Drupal 6) with roughly 2000 nodes the search index is stuck at 76% (saying 944 nodes are left to be indexed).

Besides 944 not being 24% of about 2000, it isn't changing persistently no more. If I run the cron, 50 nodes are indexed and `/admin/settings/search` states, that 77% are done and 894 nodes are left.

However, when only reloading that page, the displayed information is reset to 76% and 944 nodes left.

I tried to re-index, though it is not resetting to 0% but stays at 76% and 944 nodes left.

The MySQL table `search_index` has crashed about a week ago and I repaired it through phpMyAdmin (repair table option).

How should I proceed to get it all working again? Do I have to empty tables to start over? If yes, which ones should I empty?

Comment: This is likely due to an issue with cron getting stalled. Are there any messages in your log files related to cron run errors?

Comment: No, actually it always says 'Cron run successful.' No errors at all.